# Translate x and y with a different timing functions?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Currently I'm using the following code to translate both x and y at the same speed:

```
-webkit-transition:all 180ms ease-out;
```

I would like to translate the X axis slower than the Y.  Is it possible to specify something similar to:

```
-webkit-transition:translateX 180ms ease-out;
-webkit-transition:translateY 50ms ease-out;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Sad but true: you can't use different timings for different parts of `transform` since it's now only one property and cannot be spliced.

The only things you can do:

- Use `translate` only for one axis, and use the positioning for another (like `top` or `left`). Doing so you could attach different timings.
- Use two wrapped blocks, so you could use different `transform`s on them. It would take more code, but would be helpful if you'll need the GPU acceleration.

No other ways for us :(

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but you could translate one dimension and change another property, such as `left` on the other...

```
-webkit-transition: left 180ms ease-out, -webkit-transform 50ms ease-out;
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/DFLL7/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but maybe you can try.

```
.m01 { -webkit-animation:test_XY 3.5s 1.5s ease both;  }



@-webkit-keyframes test_XY {
0%{ -webkit-transform:translateX(450px)}
70%{ -webkit-transform:translateX(-1px)}
80%{ -webkit-transform:translateX(0)}
95%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(-95px)}
100%{ -webkit-transform:translateY(-90px)}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Iris Monkey.